# Android Picasso - On device rotate, refresh images

Tags: android, image, caching, size, picasso

I love Picasso and am using it for image caching in my app, where each list item has an image. The image is scaled correctly when shown, but when the user rotates their device, the image is the same old dimensions. However, when I scroll down and back up to the image, it is correct. How can I make the list refresh its images?